# Mapbox Heatmap only streets

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'd like to apply a color overlay to certain streets relative to their value.
Eg.:

`{Street1: 5,
    Street2: 1,
    Street3: 8,
Street4: 10}`

In this case `street 4` should have 100% opacity red and `street 1` 10% opacity red. I was thinking about using the heatmap feature, but don't really know how to apply it only to the streets as it is thought to work with point values.

Any ideas on how I could achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Show your attempts and how far you managed to go.

Comment: Well, I managed to make a Heatmap overlay but that’s not the right direction, as it’s visualization is based on point coordinates and I want to tint whole roads.

Comment: This is understandable from your question, but how do you, for example, indicate which streets exactly should be painted in what color? Sample code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @stdob-- i'd use the streetnames. I'd like to highlight 5th ave for example. I imagine the data would also be used when calculating navigation routes.